# Number sequence AX 2012

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have gone through msdn article, read whitepaper on number sequences and made number sequences a lot many times. But in this scenario I need some help.

*Scenario is;* I want to get next sequence number through x++ code using just **number sequence code** and **no reference** etc.

I have tried following (and many others but this is nearest solution) ;

```
static void myTestJob(Args _args)
{
    NumberSeq  num;

    num = NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode('SAO-Y');

     info(num.num())  ;
}
```

It generates number sequence against some number sequence codes, but for other it throws error that;

> "Number sequence  does not exist."

I have tried many other options mentioned on many other blogs and tried to explore AX as well, but now need some assistance.

*P.S. I'm not creating number sequence using x++ code but from front end (organization administration).*

Comment: Just a thought, when you run the job, are you in the company in which the number sequence was created ?

Comment: Yea, same thought flashed in my mind, but I was in the same company.

Comment: For what kind of entry are you trying to get a number for ? A voucher, a journal, an account, etc. ? The only time I used number sequences programmatically was to get a new voucher number and I used a function that explicitly does so it seems called "newGetVoucherFromCode"

Comment: An account; I need to create it for sales order, (i'm using OOTB sales order sequence number as well, but need to make another one for some requirement). And need to assign different number sequences against different sales order types (custom field).

Comment: Is 'SAO-Y' indeed the number sequence code defined in the "General" tab of Number Sequence set up ? I know these are very basic questions here but you never know...

Comment: Lol! yea, number sequences have been set up with desired format etc.

Comment: Did you create the number sequence by just clicking the new button or using the "Wizard" button ?

Comment: Not through wizard but New Number Sequence form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43529/discussion-between-bilal-saeed-and-francis-ducharme)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to suppress the exception by using following;

`num = NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode(<<someNumberSequenceCode>>, NumberSeqScopeFactory::createDefaultScope(), true, true);`

As, fourth optional parameter of NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode(,,,true); says not to throw exception on missing reference.

`boolean             _dontThrowOnMissingRefSetUp  = false,`

As I said earlier, I have created number sequence from organization administration without writing any code (EDT, class, parameters table etc. stuff) so no reference was generated and I think I was getting exception due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at your number sequence that you have set up. I recon it has something to do with the numbersequence scope.

Make sure the scope of the number sequence is valid within the company you are calling this.

Answer (score 0):

It's work, but not raice  result: Voucher not generated.

Working way:

```
 num = NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode(<<someNumberSequenceCode>>, 
NumberSeqScopeFactory::createDefaultScope(), **false**, true);
```

Comment: More usefull way found. Work more stabile: LedgerJournalTrans.Voucher = new JournalVoucherNum(JournalTableData::newTable(ledgerJournalTable)).getNew(false);

Answer (score 0):

When my Number Sequence - Scope is setup as *Shared* I can use this code:

```
numSequence = NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode(<<someNumberSequenceCode>>, NumberSeqScopeFactory::createDataAreaScope(curext()), true, true);
```

When my Number Sequence - Scope is setup as *Company* I can use this code:

```
numSequence = NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode(<<someNumberSequenceCode>>);
```